# Setting html button to call javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, button, call

as title says, im trying to get this button to call the js function for pause on a pong game,and failing miserably.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" id="pause" value="Pause">
</body>

<script>
var isPaused = false;
var ballSpeedx = 0;
var ballSpeedy = 0; 

var pauseGame = function(Ball){ 
  document.getElementById("pause").onclick = function(Ball){
    if(isPaused === true) {
      Ball.x_speed = ballSpeedx;
      Ball.y_speed = ballSpeedy;
      isPaused = false;              

    } else if(isPaused === false){
      ballSpeedx = Ball.x_speed;
      ballSpeedy = Ball.y_speed; 
      Ball.x_speed =0;
      Ball.y_speed =0;
      isPaused = true;
    }
};
</script>

</html>
```

did a minor edit as robg suggested, nothing changed. Clicking on the button does not activate the function.

Comment: How are you failing? What's the problem?

Comment: it always paused ? is it the problem ?

Comment: You are calling the *onclick* property instead of assigning to it, use something like: `document.getElementById("pause").onclick = function(){...}`. Fixing the indenting also shows syntax errors.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm trying to have the button clicked and pausing the movement of the ball in the game. But clicking on the button proves fruitless. I cant find the issue with it

Comment: Wow, 4 close votes and two down votes. You guys realize that this is the OP's first question. Can we be any less welcoming?

Answer (score 1):

You don't attempt to assign the event handler to the button's click event until the `pauseGame` function is called, but you never call that function, so clicking on the button will never do anything.

You also haven't defined `Ball` so that code inside the function would error anyway.

```js
var isPaused = false;
var ballSpeedx = 0;
var ballSpeedy = 0;

function pauseGame(event) {

  alert("The function runs");
  
  /* Commented out because Ball is not defined
  if (isPaused === true) {
    Ball.x_speed = ballSpeedx;
    Ball.y_speed = ballSpeedy;
    isPaused = false;
  } else if (isPaused === false) {
    ballSpeedx = Ball.x_speed;
    ballSpeedy = Ball.y_speed;
    Ball.x_speed = 0;
    Ball.y_speed = 0;
    isPaused = true;
  }
  */
};

document.getElementById("pause").onclick = pauseGame
```

```html
<input type="button" id="pause" value="Pause">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is:

```
var pauseGame = function(Ball){
```

Why use a function expression rather than a declaration? Why not:

```
function pauseGame(ball) {
```

then:

```
  document.getElementById("pause").onclick = function(Ball) {
```

Though a safer strategy is:

```
  var button = document.getElementById("pause");
  if (button) {
    button.onclick = function(Ball) {
```

then:

```
    if (isPaused === true) {
```

since *isPaused* is boolean, you can do:

```
    if (isPaused) {

      Ball.x_speed = ballSpeedx;
      Ball.y_speed = ballSpeedy;
      isPaused = false;              

    } else if(isPaused === false){
```

There's no need for the second test. If *isPaused* doesn't evaluate to true, it must be false, there is nothing in between, so just:

```
    } else {

      ballSpeedx = Ball.x_speed;
      ballSpeedy = Ball.y_speed; 
      Ball.x_speed =0;
      Ball.y_speed =0;
      isPaused = true;
    }
```

So Ball is an object, but you don't show how it's created or what it's properties are so I'll assume it's OK.

Then:

```
});
```

Neither a function expression or declaration should end like that. The function is not called so the listener is not added to the button. Perhaps you want:

```
var isPaused = false;
var bolaSpeedx = 0;
var bolaSpeedy = 0; 

function pauseGame (Ball) { 
  document.getElementById("pause").onclick = function(Ball) {
    if (isPaused) {
      Ball.x_speed = ballSpeedx;
      Ball.y_speed = ballSpeedy;
      isPaused = false;              

    } else {
      ballSpeedx = Ball.x_speed;
      ballSpeedy = Ball.y_speed; 
      Ball.x_speed =0;
      Ball.y_speed =0;
      isPaused = true;
    }
  };
}
```

Now call the function to add the listener to the button:

```
pauseGame(...);
```

Comment: Thanks! can't really upvote yet though.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("pause").onclick = function(Ball){
```

have

```
var myPause = function(){
//initialize Ball
```

and change your button to

```
<input type="button" id="pause" value="Pause" onclick = "myPause()">
```

Finally, you have some `Ball`s but we do not really see how you initialize your `Ball`s. Make sure they are properly initialized.

Comment: The *onclick* handler needs to call the function: `<input ... onclick="myPause()">`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG, that's right, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Isn't it better practice to have the event handler in JS?

Comment: It depends. In that case you must make sure that your button already exists when your JS code runs.